# Writing DWORD Value to Registry in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, registry

I have this code and, essentially, I want to make it so the program writes a `DWORD` value to the registry instead of an "SV" type.

This is my code:

```
My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\", True).SetValue("TestKey", "1")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k23f0345%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) about the method which shows that there is an additional parameter with the [kind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryvaluekind(v=vs.110).aspx) of value to write

So try this

```
My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("...", True).SetValue("TestKey", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
```